# Is it possible to manipulate real photos with SVG? Resize, create thumbnails

Tags: svg, image-manipulation, image-resizing

I'm looking for something like GD Library but for JavaScript. I read about SVG.

> SVG images can be searched, indexed, scripted, and compressed
>
> SVG graphics do NOT lose any quality if they are zoomed or resized
>
> SVG images are scalable

But only images I could see in examples that SVG manipulates with are simple rectangles, circles, polylines and so on. Just children's free-hand drawing images. And I still don't understand is it possible to manipulate real photos with SVG?

Comment: SVG can display images via the `<image>` tag, and can display them at various scaled sizes and transformations, but it does not provide features for resampling and exporting the raw data. Try HTML5 Canvas if you need to do this on the web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SVG is meant for vector graphics, not raster images like JPEG.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics